# Will landlord be held liable for failing to meet NJ Security Deposit reporting laws?

Tags: real-estate, landlord

I am dealing with a NJ dispute. I am on the tenant side. Any clarity would be greatly appreciated. Or if you could point me in the right direction to get some answers.

1. The landlord must notify tenant of security deposit bank details within 30 days…if they do not, does it become the tenant’s responsibility to request it?
2. Is there a “notice of cure” that needs to be supplied by tenant allowing LL time to produce the security deposit notification? Is that for 30 days or more/less?
3. Would this hold up if the tenant was NEVER given any notification (no name of bank, statement, annual interest payments or deductions, not notified when account holding funds was changed - nothing) from day one, through a 6-year tenancy?
4. Once the request for documentation is made - upon termination of lease - does that preclude the LL from their original responsibility of supplying this information 30 days after the lease was signed and 30 days if the account where held is changed?

Comment: crickets...chirp, chirp